# Rearranging transfer function for Bode diagram

Tags: transfer-function

[image]

Hi, I have been given this circuit and need to find its transfer function for then realizing its Bode diagram. 
The problem is that I don't know how to arrange the terms to find the asymptotes of the diagram. 
After some calculations I found : \$\frac{j\omega*R3*(R1+R2)Ca - \omega^2*R1R2R3CaCb}{j\omega*R1*(R2Cb+R3Ca) + R1 - \omega^2*R1R2R3CaCb}\$

I don't know if I am correct about this equation and even if I am I don't know how to find the cutoff frequencies of this transfer function can anybody help me please ?

Comment: What happens if you set Cb=0 ? The transfer function must be reduced to a first order RC-function multiplied by (1+R2/R1). Does this happen? If not - the function H(s) is not cottect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the electronics stack-exchange! 
I would go the approach of R.D middlebrook and do the analysis in the style of "design-oriented analysis" This means that I would first split up the circuit, and do algebra "on the circuit".

First separation:
We see that the RC filter can be separated out from the rest of the circuit because it is not loaded by the opamp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTAcwJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$H(s)' =\frac{uo'}{ui'} = \frac{(C_a\cdot s)^{-1}}{R_3 + (C_a\cdot s)^{-1}} = \frac {1}{{R_3C_a\cdot s}+1}$$

first one down. 
now to the opamp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fePUpY.png)</sup>

We see that this is a common amplifier configuration with the formula
$$H = \frac{Z_2}{Z_1} + 1$$ where $$Z_1 = R_3$$ and Z_2 is R_1 in parallel with C_3.

So we see that
$$H(s)'' = \frac{uo''}{ui''} = \frac{R_2 || C_b}{R_1} +1 = \frac{(R_2^{-1} +(\frac{1}{C_b\cdot s})^{-1})^{-1}}{R_1} +1 = \left |\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_2} + C_b\cdot s}\right|_{\cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1}} \cdot \frac{1}{R_1} +1 $$$$= \frac{R_2}{R_1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+R_2C_b\cdot s}+1$$

So the total transfer function is
$$\left(  \frac {1}{{R_3C_a\cdot s}+1}\right)\cdot \left (\frac{R_2}{R_1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+R_2C_b\cdot s}+1\right)$$

from this you can see that we have 2 cutoff frequecies. the first one being $$\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot R_3 C_a}$$ and the second one: $$\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot R_2 C_b}$$ ( given that the input node on the opamp is virtual ground)

I hope that my answer gives you another perspective on how to analyze circuits, in an easier way.

Comment: I think, the first transfer function is wrong!! This is a highpass function - however, the RC block is a lowpass. I ask myself how somebody could positively vote for this (false) answer

Comment: More than that - I am surprised to read Z2=R2||C1.

Comment: @LvW You're right that the transfer function is wrong for the first 1st order lowpass. But if he corrects that, he gets it right. He probably meant Xc, so he should correct that, too. OP must have upvoted it in an enthusiastic moment, but that only shows that OP tends to jump to conclusions, which is a dangerous thing in engineering.

Comment: Yes - I agree. Everybody can make errors. However, before accepting an answer as correct (blindly believing that it would be correct) one should critically review the answer - in order to UNDERSTAND the background and the content of the answer. That is the main point of my comment.

Comment: @LvW Hi. Thanks for correcting my errors. I'm a little bit embarrassed that I got that wrong. Editing Asap .

Comment: You're just one step from the answer so far. The +1 inside the second parenthesis is not good. What is the zero frequency?More,  I should anyway have DC gain as a factor to the whole transfer function, think this over.

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at this circuit is to apply the fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371) formalized by Dr. Middlebrook some years ago. This 2nd-order filter is actually the cascading of two 1st-order filters that can separately be solved:

[image]

Considering an infinite impedance at the NINV input (the op-amp is considered perfect), the first circuit is a classical low-pass filter governed by the following transfer function: \$H_1(s)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p1}}}\$ with \$\omega_{p1}=\frac{1}{R_3C_a}\$.

For the second filter, we can show that this structure obeys the following expression: \$H_2(s)=\frac{H_0+H^1s\tau_1}{1+s\tau_1}\$ In this expression, \$H_0\$ designates the gain determined for \$s=0\$ and obtained by open-circuiting capacitor \$C_b\$. If you compute the gain in this non-inverting configuration, you should find: \$H_0=\frac{R_2}{R_1}+1\$.

The time constant \$\tau_1\$ is obtained by reducing the excitation to 0 V (shorting the \$V_{in}\$ source) and finding the resistance "seen" from the connections of \$C_b\$. This is the \$R?\$ exercise in the below picture:

[image]

By inspection, the only resistance you see if the open-loop gain is infinite is \$R_2\$ leading to \$\tau_1=R_2C_b\$. It gives a second pole located at \$\omega_{p2}=\frac{1}{R_2C_b}\$.

The zero can be obtained by calculating a gain \$H^1\$ in which capacitor \$C_b\$ is set in its high-frequency state (a short circuit). In this case, we have \$H^1=1\$ and the numerator of \$H_2\$ can be written as: \$N(s)=H_0(1+\frac{H^1}{H_0}s\tau_1)\$ which if you develop and rearrange this gives you the second intermediate transfer function: \$H_2(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_{z1}}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p2}}}\$ with \$\omega_{z1}=\frac{1}{(R_2||R_1)C_b}\$ and \$\omega_{p2}=\frac{1}{R_2C_b}\$.

Finally, cascading the two transfer functions leads to the final expression you want, written in a so-called *low-entropy* format:

\$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_{z1}}}{(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p1}})(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p2}})}\$ with

\$\omega_{z1}=\frac{1}{(R_2||R_1)C_b}\$
\$\omega_{p1}=\frac{1}{R_3C_a}\$
\$\omega_{p2}=\frac{1}{R_2C_b}\$
\$H_0=\frac{R_2}{R_1}+1\$

We can check these calculations with a simple Mathcad sheet comparing the brute-force approach and the FACTs: results are identical.

[image]
[image]

The adopted approach can appear a bit obscure to some readers but it's not and the technique is well formalized nowadays. The book given in the introduction is a possibility to explore these FACTs as well as the book from [Vorpérian](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CEKKJEU) and all the papers found on-line. Learning the FACTs in 2019 is certainly a good project!

Comment: +1 I have Vorperian and Basso books but I just need to really grok the process to just apply it when I see networks

Comment: If you start learning the FACTs, you won't go back to the classical approach : ) A good stepping stone is this APEC 2016 seminar: http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf

Comment: ahh thanks, I have another one of basso's presentation where he is deploying FACTS, but because it was extremely demain specific it jumpled over a few of the basic steps. The concept makes perfect sense, I just need to use it a bit more to get use to open/shorting C/L at each point. The low-entropy forms are what drew me to all of this a few years back